# Unclaim a device

Tags: kernel-modules, devices, debugging

So I am using Ubuntu and trying to use some hardware which I had some problems with before.

The problem before was that the company who made my hardware sold their internal parts to another company who made some different hardware with the same ID. Someone kindly made a driver for it which came with Ubuntu, but stopped the driver for my device from working. On my last system I just tracked down the kernel module and disabled it.

I am getting the same message as on my previous machine:

> Could not claim device (Vid: 0x2457, Pid: 0x1002, iface: 0)

but plugging in the device does not seem to create an entry in /dev like before. How can I find what is claiming my device? I assume that the dmesg:

> usb 4-1: new full speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 16

is just saying that it is being detected and it is not ohci that is blocking my access.

Comment: What are your kernel and ubuntu versions? What was the kernel driver you had to disable before?

Answer (score 1):

You could try (as root):

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

Then look for your device, and see which driver is handling it.

If you can run your application as root, you may want to try that to see if it is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could blacklist the module claiming the device under `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`  To determine the driver using the device use `lsusb -t`